# error using while loop in ubuntu shell script

Tags: linux, shell-script, ubuntu

I am new to shell scripting and I am trying to learn while loop in an ubuntu shell script.
Script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
#Initializing two variables
#while loop

echo while loop
a=0
while [ $a -lt 10 ]
do 
echo $a
a=$(a + 1) 
done
```

Output is -

```
vscoder@vscoder-VirtualBox:~$ ./script.sh
while loop
0
./script.sh: line 10: a: command not found
./script.sh: line 7: [: -lt: unary operator expected
vscoder@vscoder-VirtualBox:~$
```

I have no idea what is the error. Somebody please help me with the issue.

Comment: Arithmetic would work like: `a=$(( a + 1 ))`. Note you need to count upwards to meet the exit condition. A for loop would be a better construct here: `for a in {0..9}; do ... done` or `for (( a = 0; a < 10; a++ )); do ... done`.

Comment: The actual syntax error is that numeric comparison requires `-lt` (less than) and similar. `<` is being interpreted as a file redirection, with 10 as the filename. `shellcheck.net` is your friend here.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant actually, inside the `[ ]`, the `<` is not redirection but lexicographic comparison. See `help test`.

Comment: Mayank, what do you want this loop to do? Even if you get the current code right, that will be an infinite loop that never exits. Please [edit] and tell us what you want to achieve here. Also, please take the time to read some tutorials or the bash manual or _anything_ really. You need to learn the basic syntax of a language before you can try using it.

Comment: @terdon The _unquoted_ `<` is a redirection (in `[ ... ]`, not in `[[ ... ]]`). Quoting it makes it compare sort order.

Comment: Well I'll be... You're quite right, @Kusalananda.

Comment: Line 7 throws `10: No such file or directory`, and line 10 throws `0: command not found`. (Even the comment in line 2 is wrong -- there is only one variable, which is in fact constant.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what's happening:

- the first time through the while loop, `a == 0` so `[ $a -lt 10 ]` is true
- we enter the loop and execute `a=$(a + 1)`
- because this is [Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) not [Arithmetic Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arithmetic-Expansion), the shell

  - attempts to execute the program `a` with arguments `+` and `1`
  - the `a: command not found` error is thrown
  - the stdout of the command substitution is assigned to variable `a`: this is an empty string
- we loop back and test the condition again

  - because `$a` is an empty string, and because we're using `[` not `[[` , and because `$a` is unquoted, the shell sees this: `[ -lt 10 ]`
  - `-lt` is not a unary operator (see [the `test` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-test) and [Bash Conditional Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions) ), and the error message is thrown
  - `[` exits with a non-zero status, so `while` stops looping.

Answer (score 0):

**While comparison need to change and assignment of a variable**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo while loop
a=0
while [[ $a -lt 10 ]]
do
echo $a
a=$(($a+1))
done
```

Comment: (a) Invalid shebang -- no space allowed before #!. (b) You need to count *up* to reach the terminal condition. (c) This actually exits after one iteration, because it counts down to `-1` and then does a string comparison of "-1" < "10".

Comment: Since the edit, it just loops  (0, -1, -2, -3, ...). I expected it to stop with overflow from -2147483648 to +2147483647, but it uses 64-bit ints and wraps from -9223372036854775808 to +9223372036854775807.

Comment: I have did the changes in the script. Its running from 1 to 9 and stops the execution.